# PID lookup to recall and kill task

Tags: cmd, pid

I'd like to create the below two separate lines of cmd script into a bat file. The PID changes so I'm having a hard time figuring out how to set this service PID to be dynamic.
Any help would be welcomed thank you!!

sc queryex DWDesktopService

taskkill /f /pid ####

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to scrape the PID value out of the `sc` output. It is awkward in cmd scripting. Change the service name to yours. When you are satisfied that the correct PID will be killed, remove the `echo` from the TASKKILL line.

```
FOR /F "usebackq delims=: tokens=1,2" %%a IN (`sc queryex "BITS" ^| FIND /I " PID "`) DO (
    SET "PID=%%b"
)
echo TASKKILL /F /PID %PID%
```

Comment: @JoeBrawley - I am glad that it works for you. Please click on the large check mark to the left of the answer to indicate that this is correct. Thanks.